# ¿cómo crear una matriz dinámica a partir los datos de un fichero?

Tags: java, array, matrices, array-bidimensional

[image]

Me dan este fichero txt necesito crear una función que me devuelva una matriz n x n con los datos del fichero.  He hecho lo siguiente pero no me sale. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

```
public static int[][] leerFichero(String fich) throws FileNotFoundException{
    
    int[][] matriz = null;
    File f=new File("archivo.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String linea= sc.nextLine();
            Scanner s=new Scanner (linea).useDelimiter(" ");
            int num=s.nextInt();
            
            
            int filas=0;
            int columnas=0;
            
            matriz= new int[filas][columnas];
            for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++) {
                for(int j=0;i<matriz[i].length;i++) {
                    matriz[i][j]=num;
                }
                
            }
            
            s.close();
        }
    
    
    return matriz;
```

imprime por pantalla: [[I@2e5d6d97

Comment: Para imprimir una arreglo hazlo con   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
En tu duda te hace falta mostrar que es lo que contiene el archivo, a partir de ahí te podremos ayudar a generar la matriz.